# In Flask sqlalchemy, inserting data to the parent class fails - one to many relationship

Tags: python, mysql

In Flask, I would like to insert data to parent class using `sqlalchemy`.
My database consists of two tables - parent class (`Person()`) and children class (`List()`).

This is the snippet code I've written.

```
....
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "persons"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    dateAdd = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    dateChange = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    fList = db.relationship("lists")

    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, dateAdd, dateChange, fList):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.dateAdd = dateAdd
        self.dateChange = dateChange
        self.fList = fList


class List(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "lists"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    persId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    listName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    fItem = db.relationship("items")

    def __init__(self, persId, listName, fItem):
        self.persId = persId
        self.listName = listName
        self.fItem = fItem
```

As you can see on this code, one person can have multiple lists.

When I tried to insert **person info** - such as `firstName, lastName...` into `persons` table, I got error like this.

```
__init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (4 given)
```

I think this happens because of `fList`, but I'm not sure `fList` should be necessary for `initialization`. Because when I inserted data without relationship, it works well.

How can I handle it?

Comment: Well the error is clear. You called `Person(a,b,c)` (with three arguments), but you need to specify **two additional ones**...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but would you explain it for me more detail?